# Why a Wikipedia API query returns HTML content instead of XML?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wikipedia-api

I tried to use the Wikipedia API in my app, to display the things that we type on a TextBox.
After we click the Button, the API should return an XML file, based on what I typed on the TextBox.
However, when I use WebClient's `DownloadString()` method, the method returns HTML content instead of XML; why this is happening?
when I use the URL in a WebBrowser, it can be opened and displayed correctly.

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var webclient = new WebClient();
    var pageSourceCode = webclient.DownloadString("http://id.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?Format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=" + textBox1.Text + "&redirects=true");

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(pageSourceCode);

    //This line causes an exception, because it's HTML
    var fnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("extract")[0];

    try
    {
        string ss = fnode.InnerText;
        Regex regex = new Regex("\\<[^\\>]*\\>");
        string.Format("Before: {0}", ss);
        ss = regex.Replace(ss, string.Empty);
        string result = string.Format(ss);
        richTextBox1.Text = result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "error";
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why the content is HTML.

Comment: I assume the 2nd call to `DownloadString` should read `webclient.DownloadString`?  Please copy (from your IDE) and paste code when posting a question rather than typing it in again **by hand**.  This serves to minimise typos in your question and avoids issues which do not exist in the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters in the query are case-sensitive.

```
https://id.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
  Format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=" + textBox1.Text + "&redirects=true"
```

Here, the `format` field is written with a capital letter, `Format`, so the parser doesn't recognize it and it's assumed you have not specified a format.
In this case, what you get back is an HTML page that describes the contents of a successful query, informs that a format has not been specified and adds a sample result in JSON format.

The protocol should be set to `https`

Also, consider that WebClient is disposable, so declare it with an `using` statement:

```
string pageSourceCode = string.Empty;

using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    pageSourceCode = client.DownloadString(
        "https://id.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=" + 
        textBox1.Text + 
        "&redirects=true");
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageSourceCode)) return;

// The rest
```

---

I'd suggest replacing WebClient with [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) as soon as possible, since the former has been marked as `obsolete` in more recent versions of .NET

With this class, your code could look like this:
(Note the async / await keywords. A HttpClient object is created once and used many times)

```
using System.Net.Http;

// Simplified but functional declaration 
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pageSourceCode = await client.GetStringAsync("[The query]");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageSourceCode)) return;

    // The rest
}
```